# regex replacing text

Tags: c#, regex

i need a regex to replace a string.

```
<span class=\"Translation\" lang=\"ThisLanguage\">
```

with this one:

```
<span class=\"Translation\" lang=\"ThisLanguage\" onDblClick=\"window.external.MyFunction(ThisLanguage)\">
```

there are many languages in this string, each one contains a different "ThisLanguage"

anyone knows how it can be done??

I'm working with C# .Net

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit verbose but [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) saves a lot of time!

```
//  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Thu, Mar 11, 2010, 04:37:21 PM
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.2766, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  <span.*?class="
///      <span
///      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
///      class="
///  [1]: A numbered capture group. [.*?]
///      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
///  ".*?lang="
///      "
///      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
///      lang="
///  [2]: A numbered capture group. [.*?]
///      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
///  ">
///      ">
///  
///
/// </summary>
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      "<span.*?class=\"(.*?)\".*?lang=\"(.*?)\">",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );


// This is the replacement string
public static string regexReplace = 
      "<span class=\"$1\" lang=\"$2\" onDblClick=\"window.external."+
      "MyFunction(ThisLanguage)\">\r\n";


//// Replace the matched text in the InputText using the replacement pattern
// string result = regex.Replace(InputText,regexReplace);

//// Split the InputText wherever the regex matches
// string[] results = regex.Split(InputText);

//// Capture the first Match, if any, in the InputText
// Match m = regex.Match(InputText);

//// Capture all Matches in the InputText
// MatchCollection ms = regex.Matches(InputText);

//// Test to see if there is a match in the InputText
// bool IsMatch = regex.IsMatch(InputText);

//// Get the names of all the named and numbered capture groups
// string[] GroupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();

//// Get the numbers of all the named and numbered capture groups
// int[] GroupNumbers = regex.GetGroupNumbers();
```

Comment: Don't you need to capture what's between `span` and `class`? I mean, if there *is* something? :). From the example it only looks like a space.

Comment: @Vivin, that's a fair comment (+1) although I think this was a fairly tight requirement. So replacing the search regex with "<span(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)lang=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>" and the replacement string with "<span$1class=\"$2\"$3lang=\"$4\"$5  onDblClick=\"window.external.MyFunction(ThisLanguage)\">" should do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not advisable to parse HTML with regexps, since HTML is *not regular* and there are sufficient edge cases to trip up all but the most trivial scenarios. For all but the most trivial examples I would rather parse the HTML via an HTML parser and manipulate it via a suitable API (e.g. a DOM)

Comment: Dis-recommending regex for HTML parsing jobs is like beating a flour sack. You can beat on it all you like, it will never stop raising dust.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML with regex is like the 10th circle of hell. I kid you not. You'd be better off `tidy`ing it up (not sure if .NET has tidy) and then running it through an XML parser. That way you can pull out specific attributes like `class` and `lang` and then add a new attribute called `onDblClick` to your `span` node.

Otherwise, a naive approach (not sure what the syntax is in .NET but this is in Perl):

```
$str =~ s/<span\(.*?\)lang=\\"\(.*?\)\\">/<span$1lang=\\"$2\\" onDblClick=\\"window.external.MyFunction($2)\\">/
```

The important thing here is the pattern to match (including captures):

```
<span\(.*\)lang=\\"\(.*?\)\\">
```

This matches `<span` followed by anything, followed by `lang=\"` with anything between the `\"`s, followed by `\">`.

The replacement pattern is:

```
<span$1lang=\\"$2\\" onDblClick=\\"window.external.MyFunction($2)\\">
```

This creates `<span` followed by everything it matched up to the `lang` (`$1`) and then `lang=\"` followed by the language name it captured (`$2`), followed by the `onDblClick` stuff.

I am not familiar with .NET, so you will have to convert this. But it shouldn't be too different. You might have to change the `\(` to just `(` (depending on the syntax). Also I'm not sure how .NET handles back-references but it should be `$1` and `$2` (like in Java).

Note: I have NOT tested this!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex. I would use jQuery.

```
// set the lang value to ThisLanguage
$('span.Translation').attr('lang', 'ThisLanguage'); 
// add the onDblClick event with the value
$('span.Translation').attr('onDblClick', 'window.external.MyFunction(ThisLanguage)');
```

Or if you are simply generating strings (Which you may not be but **IF** you are this could work) and pushing them out why not do this?

```
string spanTag = String.Format("<span class=\"Translation\" lang=\"{0}\" onDblClick=\"window.external.MyFunction({0})\">", "ThisLanguage");
```

Comment: There is a jQuery port for C#? Nice! ;-)